# Emacs find-and-replace regex in multiple files (find-name-dired + Q), doesn't save my buffers?

Tags: emacs

I can't figure out what's going on here.  I've done a search and replace across a whole directory, using:

1. M-x find-name-dired RET
2. Select root of my project
3. Enter *.rb as the filenames to match
4. Press "t" to select all files found
5. Press "Q" (shift Q) to start the search/replace
6. Enter "transaction" as the query, then enter "invoice" as the replacement

Now I've cycled through all the buffers it opens for me, selectively press "y" or "n" depending on the replacement.  When it finished, it just left me in the last buffer I had changed.

So, hitting C-z to background the emacs window and check what has changed, shows that none of the files are saved, which I expected.

So then I did `M-x save-some-buffers RET`, which tells me there are no files to be saved.  So I start rotating through my buffers with C-x b and verify that, yes indeed, the buffers *do* have changes compared to what is on disk.

So I repeat the process, this time with a completely fresh emacs process (no open buffers at all when I start the process).  At the end I have a bunch of buffers open, with changes (that I can see), yet again, emacs says there's nothing to save.

So I tried using C-x C-b to bring up IBuffer.  Marked all the files I wanted to save, then hit "S" to save them, at which point it shows "Operation finished; saved 27 buffers".  Awesome... except git is still telling me that emacs has in fact saved nothing.

What am I doing wrong?  I want to replace "transaction" with "invoice" across my entire project, though I do need to do it interactively, since there are some places where that replacement should not be done.

Emacs 23.

Comment: Even if I go to an individual buffer of these 27 changed buffers, then hit C-x C-s, it says there's nothing to save, but there actually is.  If I then hit the space bar, then delete the space character again, and cit C-x C-s, *now* it saves (git shows the changes). WTF?

Comment: Is there a way to tell emacs to forcefully consider all buffers dirty?  If it thinks the buffer is dirty, then it will happily save it, but I have to type on the keyboard in each buffer to make that happen.

Comment: C-u M-~ will flag the current buffer as modified.

Comment: Thanks, I've used this one one buffer with success.  Is there a way to do that across all buffers?  I don't understand how Emacs has ended up in this state, but going through all 27 buffers and repeating that key combination doesn't seem like a good solution if this is going to happen every time I use Find and Replace :P

Comment: I'd use M-x list-buffers (C-x C-b) and write a macro which selects a buffer, does C-u M-~ and then selects the next buffer.  Then, just iterate the macro 27 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reproed the behaviour you describe.  Sure smells like a bug to me.  Please report it at bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.

The Emacs contributors are very responsive.

P.S.  Love the details you put into your question.

Comment: Reported it, and checked out emacs from git, built the current HEAD and it seems to be working fine now.  Must have been an issue in 23.3.1 stable, I guess.