# How do I disable find-name-dired's default -iname option?

Tags: emacs, replace, dired

I wanted to run a `query-replace-regexp` across multiple files in emacs, and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321589/emacs-find-and-replace-regex-in-multiple-files-find-name-dired-q-doesnt-sa) explaining how to do it. When I tried following the directions, I got an error after entering the file wildcard.

```
find . \( -iname \*.vb \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;
Unknown option "-iname"
```

Unfortunately, the `find` I'm using is from MKS Toolkit on Windows, and it doesn't support the `-iname` option. I tried replacing all occurences of "iname" with "name" in my emacs lisp files, and then byte-compiling and restarting emacs. This did not solve the problem and I got exactly the same error as before. After a bit more digging, I found another command `find-dired` that lets you customize the find command used, so I've already done the search and replace with this workaround.

My question is this: Why am I still getting the `-iname` error, even after editing my source files, re-byte-compiling them, and restarting emacs? I'd like to find a more permanent solution for future search-and-replace across multiple files (and to satisfy my curiosity).

Comment: Editing Emacs' own elisp files is generally a bad idea, and only as permanent as that installation of that version of Emacs. You want to be fixing this via your init file (or site-lisp, if you want it to apply to everyone).

Comment: +1 @phils .  Elisp has a lot of functions, `eval-after-load` for example, designed to allow you to customize Emacs without changing its sources.  By changing the sources directly, you set yourself (and others) up for confusion down the road.  Imagine if you have to report a Emacs bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the variable `find-name-arg`.  Run <kbd>M-x customize-group find-dired</kbd>, or just put `(setq find-name-arg "-name")` in your `.emacs`.

In my version of emacs, the initial value comes from `find-dired.el`.  Did you change and recompile that file?

Comment: Brilliant! It works, thank you. And yes, I changed `find-dired.el` and a couple others that have `-iname` in them to `-name`.